# Javascript não funciona no NodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js

Tenho uma pagina em html que pega algumas funções de uma pagina em Javascript, porem quando abro esta pagina pelo NodeJS o javascript não funciona.
Fiz o teste com comandos simples de Javascript e JQuery, porem ambos funcionam apenas se eu abrir diretamente meu HTML

```js
    alert("carregado alerta");



    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#idQueIdentificaP').text('JAVASCRIPT ALTEROU ESSE P')
      });
      
      
      function alterar(){
      $('#idQueIdentificaP').text('JAVASCRIPT ALTEROU ESSE P DE NOVO')
      }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.2.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="mudartexto.js"></script>
        <title>"Meu html </title>
   </head>

    <body>
        <h1> Pagina</h1>

        <p id="idQueIdentificaP"></p>   
        <button type="button" onclick="alterar()">alterar de novo</button>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="mudartexto.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

código da chamada no node:

```js
app.get("/pag", function(req,res){
    
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/html/index.html");
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use o `express.static`

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.use(express.static("public"))

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname+"/public/index.html")
})

app.listen(7005, () => {
  console.log("server running on 7005")
})
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 0):

Só para explicar pq o `express.static` funcionou.
O browser faz uma requisição ao servidor e este retorna o **index.html** conforme o código:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname+"/public/index.html")
})
```

Ao receber o html o browser interpreta o código e v que necessita carregar mais arquivo como `<script type="text/javascript" src="mudartexto.js"></script>`, daí faz outra requisição ao servidor solicitando o envio do arquivo **mudartexto.js**, neste caso o `express.static` resolve pq o arquivo está na pasta public, aliás acredito que só o `express.static` resolve nem precisa do `app.get` visto que **index.html** tbm está na pasta **public**